# How to make Python singleton class instantiation consistent across multiple modules?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class `ServerController` that implements a standard singleton design pattern. Whenever the class is instantiated in the same file in which it originated (`main.py`), it functions as expected and the first instance of the `ServerController` object is used. However, when I call the class's getter function `get_ctrl()` from another module that includes `main.py`, a new instance is created despite my singleton design pattern.

This is my singleton implementation:

```
class ServerController():
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super().__new__(cls)
            print("creating ctrl instance", cls.__instance)
        return cls.__instance

    pass
```

This is the class's `get_ctrl()` getter function:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_ctrl(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = ServerController()
        return cls.__instance
```

In my other module, I call `from main import ServerController` followed by

```
ctrl = ServerController.get_ctrl().
```

**Solution attempt 1:**

I've also attempted the [functools method](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html) which was unsuccessful:

```
@classmethod
@functools.cache
def get_ctrl(): 
    return ServerController()
```

**Solution attempt 2:**

In addition to what's shown above, I've played around with an implementation of `get_ctrl()` that is a bit different:

```
    @SingletonCache
    @classmethod
    def get_ctrl(cls):
        return cls()
```

This is accompanied by `SingletonCache` class:

```
class SingletonCache:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, cls):
        if cls not in self.cache:
            self.cache[cls] = self.func(cls)
        return self.cache[cls]
```

This method gives me the TypeError that reads,

```
SingletonCache.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

I've also tried adding the `@classmethod` decorator to `__call__(self, cls)` with no luck. I'm open to try any methods that will allow me to use a single `ServerController` object across multiple modules.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `singleton pattern`, i think the best way is to use `metaclass`.
Try this:

```py
class SingletonMeta(type):

    __instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls.__instances:
            cls.__instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.__instances[cls]


class ServerController(metaclass=SingletonMeta):

    @classmethod
    def get_ctrl(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)


s1 = ServerController()
s2 = ServerController.get_ctrl()
print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s1 == s2)
```

```bash
<__main__.ServerController object at 0x00000269013ACD00>
<__main__.ServerController object at 0x00000269013ACD00>
True
```

Comment: Would you recommend using this with my original getter function? I tried this and didn't have any luck

Comment: Okay, I gave it another shot. My output for the initial run-through is `creating ctrl instance <__main__.ServerController object at 0x000001ACA39D9D50>`. It then prints this address again when I access it a second time in main.py. However my call to `get_ctrl()` from my other module still prints `creating ctrl instance <main.ServerController object at 0x000001ACA39C2AD0>` so `cls.instance` is somehow None when `ServerController.__new__()` is called again.

Comment: You are not getting it, don't use `__new__` use `__call__` , by the way, can you show me the code in `main.py`

Comment: Is `__call__` called explicitly in ServerController? My `if __name__ == '__main__':` contains this line: 'ctrl = ServerController()'

Comment: all the `singleton` magic is handled in `SingletonMeta` no need to add `__call__`, `__new__` to `ServerController` class

Comment: Okay that's how I have it right now, the only thing in my `ServerController` class now is just member functions, `init()`, `get_ctrl()`, etc. Any calls to `get_ctrl()` from outside the `main.py` are still creating new objects

Comment: are you using the same `get_ctrl()` i defined in the answer?

Comment: Yeah, word for word

Comment: can you show me the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A few moments ago I was trying to implement an easy way to make singletons classes, complementary to class definitions, without creating subclasses. Overriding the `__new__` method and creating some internal symbols for it. You can found a functional approach [here](https://gist.github.com/px2ec/bdf92ef110ca90b94d036da9c9fe754c).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34238790)